# How to resize a UIImageView based on UIImage size and fit the screen's width

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimageview, uiimage

I have this code snippet:

```
func resizeImageViewToImageSize(_ imageView:UIImageView) {
        let widthRatio = imageView.bounds.size.width / imageView.image!.size.width
        let heightRatio = imageView.bounds.size.height / imageView.image!.size.height
        let scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        let imageWidth = scale * imageView.image!.size.width
        let imageHeight = scale * imageView.image!.size.height
        print("\(imageWidth) - \(imageHeight)")

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
        y: 70,
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight)
        imageView.center.x = view.center.x
 }
```

I call it in `viewDidLoad()` to resize my `originalImageView` UIImageView:

```
resizeImageViewToImageSize(originalImageView)
```

And it successfully resizes my UIImageView, but in case I take a picture from Camera (on iPhone7+, for instance), my imageWidth and imageHeight are: `226.4 - 283.0`, which make my UIImageView very small in the center of the screen, as shown below:

[image]

What I would like to do is to have my `originalImageView`to be larger in width and keep its scale ratio accordingly, like the mockup below, is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem arises when the value of `imageView.image!.size.width` is larger than `imageView.bounds.size.width` or for the height values.

This will result in `widthRatio` or `heightRatio` to a value less than 1.

And when your `scale` is < 1, and multiplied to your `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`, you'll end up with a smaller UIImageView than the original.

I'm guessing that the resolution of the image taken from a camera as "clear" as an iPhone7 will be high.

You'll have to check which value is higher `imageView.bounds.width` or `imageView.image!.size.width`, and then get the reciprocal depending on the condition.

```
 func resizeImageViewToImageSize(_ imageView:UIImageView) {
    

    let maxWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let maxHeight = view.frame.size.height

        var widthRatio = imageView.bounds.size.width / imageView.image!.size.width
    
        if widthRatio < 1 {
            widthRatio = 1 / widthRatio
        }
    
        var heightRatio = imageView.bounds.size.height / imageView.image!.size.height

        if heightRatio < 1 {
            heightRatio = 1 / widthRatio
        }
    
        let scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
    
        let maxWidthRatio = maxWidth / imageView.bounds.size.width
        let maxHeightRatio = maxHeight / imageView.bounds.size.height
        let maxScale = min(maxWidthRatio, maxHeightRatio)

        let properScale = min(scale, maxScale)

        let imageWidth = properScale * imageView.image!.size.width
        let imageHeight = properScale * imageView.image!.size.height
        print("\(imageWidth) - \(imageHeight)")

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
        y: 70,
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight)
        imageView.center.x = view.center.x
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so what should I do? I'm testing my code on an iPhone 7+, big screen, I must multiply imageWidth *2 and so imageHeight? I've done that before, but what about bigger images?

Comment: I think you can get the max width and height you can accommodate on your screen. Since that's really arbitrary. Unless you plan to be able to pan and zoom the image? (Then you can still set a max value or scale value).

Comment: But the next steps I'd like to advise are:
1. Check which is larger: `imageView.bounds.size.width` or `imageView.image!.size.width`
2. Use the larger value as the numerator, smaller value as the denominator (to ensure scaling up)
3. do the same for height
4. `scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)`
5. get your max scale (screenWidth / imageView.bounds.size.width)(?)
6. `usableScale = max (scale, maxScale)`
7. `imageWidth = usableScale * imageView.image!.size.width`
8. same with height

Comment: Sorry for the messy comments, it's my first time to answer and comment 

Comment: no problem, but please update your answer with your comment code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180683/discussion-between-remingtonchan-and-xscoder).

Comment: thanks, i can’t right now, i’m not on my Mac, i’ll let you know when i’ll be available again

Comment: I've edited your code, and accepted your answer, now it works fine. thanks so much!